# When I add base tag MVC Routing goes on loop

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to integrate angularjs routing in my mvc application... In this moment I have written no code about angular routing... I have just added the tag

```
<base href="/" />
```

And I run my MVC application... It has stopped working.

Here how I have configured my MVC routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have also a `Services` area and the routing is configured int this way:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Services_default",
        "Servizi/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I navigate a url in the area, the application oges on loop.

For example when I navigate `/Servizi/Cpe`, debug stops continously on the the `Index` action of the `CpeController`:

```
public class CpeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Services/Cpe
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

It's like the page is shown more than once.

Why? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved... the problem was that in the page I had a jQuery tab... so I had some `href` set to `#` :

```
<div ......>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-models">Modelli</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-info">Info</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-models">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="tab-info">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Those href create some problem when base tag is set. In my short experience I understood that often jQuery and angular does not work well togheter. 
So I prefered to move to angular material. I replaced the jQuery tab with angular material tab:

```
<div id="cpes" class="tabs" ng-cloak>
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-no-pagination>
            <md-tab label="Modelli">
                <md-content>
                    ...
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Info">
                <md-content>
                    ...
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
```